# 'module' object has no attribute 'choice' - trying to use random.choice

Tags: python, attributeerror

Could someone please tell me what I may be doing wrong. I keep getting this message when I run my python code:

```
import random

foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

random_item = random.choice(foo)

print random_item
```

Error

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'choice'

Comment: What exactly do u want to do please?

Comment: @mlwn They want to choose a random item from their list `foo`, is that not obvious?

Comment: The code works perfectly for me... Which version of python you are using? And which os?

Comment: It's obvious that it's working for you, but the possible problem is explained twice in the answers ;)

Comment: I'm running the latest version of pyCharm community edition

Comment: @AMHD: That doesn't explain _either_ of the two questions that mlwn asked, since PyCharm works with a wide range of Python versions, on at least 3 different OSs.

Comment: Another possibility is that you might have an older version of numpy.
Upgrade with: sudo pip install numpy --upgrade

Answer (score 89):

Shot in the dark: You probably named your script `random.py`. Do not name your script the same name as the module.

I say this because the `random` module indeed has a `choice` method, so the import is probably grabbing the wrong (read: undesired) module.

Comment: If this doesn't fix it, check for a random.pyc file as well.

Comment: It may be a shot in the dark, but it is an impressive shot in the dark nonetheless. +1 (Also, for the record, having a name of `math.py` causes the same problem)

Comment: this totally saved me

Answer (score 18):

The problem in my case was I used `random.choices()` with **python 3.5**. However, it is available from **python 3.6** onwards.

Instead, use `random.sample()` without the ***weights*** or ***cum_weights*** attributes you would specify in `random.choices()` if you are using python 3.5 and 2.7. Documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.sample).

Comment: use "random.sample"

Comment: `random.sample` worked for me when my production server was using python3.5. No code changes needed. Just add it. Of course please test your code before doing this.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like an import issue. Is there another module in the same directory named `random`? If so (and if you're on python2, which is obvious from `print random_item`) then it's importing that instead. Try not to shadow built-in names.

You can test this with the following code:

```
import random

print random.__file__
```

The actual `random.py` module from stdlib lives in `path/to/python/lib/random.py`. If yours is somewhere else, this will tell you where it is.

Comment: Isn't it normally `path/to/python/lib/pythonX.Y/random.py` (unless he's using a really old Python, I think before 2.3 or so)? Also, I don't think 2.7 gives you the .py file even if there's a .pyc the way 3.3+ does, so probably `random.pyc`, but I could be misremembering that. But other than that little nitpicky bit, great answer.

Comment: I saved my file is on my desktop.

Comment: @abarnert I tested on my Python3.3 and got `"C:\Python33\lib\random.py"`

Comment: @AdamSmith: Oh yeah, on Windows it leaves off the `pythonX.Y` directory because the top-level directory is already `PythonXY`.

Comment: It gives me `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'`

Comment: @Marine1 The OP on this question was running Python2, in which `python` is a statement not a function and requires no parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

I also got this error by naming a method `random` like this:

```
import random

def random():

  foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

  random_item = random.choice(foo)

  print random_item

random()
```

It's not your case (naming a file `random.py`) but for others that search about this error and may make this mistake.

Answer (score 3):

In short, Python's looking in the first file it finds named "random", and isn't finding the choice attribute.

99.99% of the time, that means you've got a file in the path/directory that's already named "random". If that's true, rename it and try again. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python older than 3.6 version, than you have to use NumPy library to achieve weighted random numbers. With the help of choice() method, we can get the random samples of one dimensional array and return the random samples of numpy array.

```
from numpy.random import choice
  
sampleList = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
randomNumberList = choice(
  sampleList, 5, p=[0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.20, 0.5])
  
print(randomNumberList)
```

source : [geeksforgeek](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-weighted-random-choice-in-python/)