# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'choice'

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am using python3.
First I use random.choice in Terminal, and it works.

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 21:31:18) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import random
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> random.choice(x)
3
```

But when I run it in my script, I get the message:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'choice'
> ```

Here is the code

```
import random
from scipy import *
from numpy import linalg as LA
import pickle
import operator


def new_pagerank_step(current_page, N, d, links):
    print(links[current_page])
    if random.rand() > 1 - d:
        next_page = random.choice(links[current_page])
    else:
        next_page = random.randint(0, N)
    return next_page


def pagerank_wikipedia_demo():
    with open("wikilinks.pickle", "rb") as f:
        titles, links = pickle.load(f)
    current_page = 0
    T = 1000
    N = len(titles)
    d = 0.4
    Result = {}
    result = []
    for i in range(T):
        result.append(current_page)
        current_page = new_pagerank_step(current_page, N, d, links)
    for i in range(N):
        result.count(i)
        Result[i] = result.count(i) / T
    Sorted_Result = sorted(Result.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

pagerank_wikipedia_demo()
```

Here, `links[i]`(`i` is an integer) is a list. When I run this script, it fails with the message mentioned above.

I have also checked that the name of the script is not `random`. And there is only one file named `random.py` in `/usr/lib/python3.2/random.py`

Why this happens?

Comment: do `import random;print(random.__file__)` at the top of your file , you probably have a file random.py in your path or a .pyc

Comment: See this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695412/module-object-has-no-attribute-choice-trying-to-use-random-choice

Comment: I have checked that and there are two files. one is random.cpython-32.pyc and one is random.py

Comment: @epx: and that is the *full path*?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I do not understand what is full path. This is what I see in Terminal Python 3.2.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 21:31:18) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import random
>>> print (random.__file__)
/usr/lib/python3.2/random.py
>>>

Comment: What's the output when you exec: `grep 'def choice' /usr/lib/python3.2/random.py`?, if this sentence doesn't print (to the console) anything, then that's right, the random module doesn't have a choice method, otherwise it must print `def choice(self, seq):`, which means that it require a sequence (i.e. a list) to select and return one element from that.

Comment: @sgmart I have seen the code in random.py and there exists a function names 'choice(self, seq)'. This makes me confused.

Comment: It seems your code isn't calling to the random module included in python. In Linux systems, you can use the command `locate random.py` to look up for the random file invoked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You masked the module with the `numpy.random` object here:

```
import random
from scipy import *
```

The `from scipy import *` import brings a *whole lot of names*, including `random`:

```
>>> from scipy import *
>>> random
<module 'numpy.random' from '/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/random/__init__.pyc'>
```

This *replaced* the random module.

Either don't use a wildcard import, or import the `random` module *after* importing everything from `scipy`.

You could also import `choice` from the `random` module and refer to it directly, or use a different name for the import to bind to:

```
from random import choice
from scipy import *

# use choice, not random.choice
```

or

```
import random as stdlib_random
from scipy import *

# use stdlib_random.choice, not random.choice
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Martijin Pieters answer I want to add that you could also import `random` module with an alias:

```
import random as rdm
from scipy import *       

# Then you can 
rdm.choice(some_sequence)
```