# Python, is "import *" bad if I am importing all classes / functions from a file?

Tags: python, import

I have heard that "import *" is not considered good practice.

So for example, in a Django app, I have created 5 models, and I want an admin page for each, is this still considered bad practice an my admin.py file?

```
from myapp.models import *
```

edit: Its my own code, I know that I want to import everything from the file.

Comment: It is a source of bugs; you don't know what names are going to be imported from the line alone. See [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587933/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-choice) where the problem was the `from scipy import *` line.

Comment: Well that's kind of the point of my question, I do know what I am importing, as its my own code.

Comment: But will you later on still remember where you used `import *` as your project evolves?

Comment: probably, I work with it every day and have a good idea of the data model.

Comment: If you are the *only* person who works with the code, it doesn't really matter what you do. If any one else is using the code, are you sure *they* will remember where `import *` is used?

Comment: @wobbily_col: so how confident are you that the project remains small enough and unimportant enough that this issue will never crop up? Why expose yourself to the risk?

Comment: Its not small. It is important. But I still know what my models are. That's my job. Anyway, I like the suggestion below to import the models and use that when referencing each one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The problem is that may add more code in the future that could cause unexpected issues; such as naming conflicts.

I normally go with:

```
from myapp.models import MyModel
from myapp.models import MySecondModel
```

An alternative would be:

```
from myapp.models import (MyModel, MySecondModel)
```

Edit:

As [@kalhartt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1460849/kalhartt) pointed out you can also simply do.

```
from myapp import models
```

And then use `models.MyModel` etc if you have to import a lot of classes.

Comment: I can see that, but I have actually had the opposite problem, where I add a new model, and add an admin page, but forget the import. Its fairly obvious at the time.

Comment: Yea, that is actually the advantage of this approach. If you forget to add something, it is going to be fairly obvious what is missing.

Comment: I currently do a bit of both, but your way end up with huge amounts of import statements. Plus I generally don't add a form or a model, without a corresponding view to use it.

Comment: @wobbily_col In the use cases you're describing, I prefer `from myapp import models` or (rarely) for brevity `import myapp.models as md`.

Comment: That's a good point.

Comment: @kalhartt: Good point. If there are a lot of them it is indeed a better solution.

Comment: Does that have the same effect as from models import * ? Or is there any difference?

Comment: I updated my answer and gave you credit @kalhartt. =]

Comment: @wobbily_col: Yes, the difference is that you don't use MyModel in your code, but rather models.MyModel.