# threading.Lock() not working through script

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x

I'm experimenting with the threading function in python 3 to get my own pingtesting app/log working, so im following a [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwH0HvMI4EA)

When I've launched a python 3 interpreter, and run:

```
>>> import threading
>>> print_lock = threading.Lock()
```

It correctly returns

```
>>> print_lock
<_thread.lock object at 0x042093C8>
```

But when I use that piece of code in a script and try to run it as

```
python scriptName.py
```

I get an error saying the attribute Lock() doesn't exist

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Lock'
```

How is this possible? I've verified what threading.Lock() returns when running the python interpreter, why isn't it recognized when I try to run it in a script and how can I get this running?

Comment: You may have a (personal) file name `threading.py` which is shadowing the standard module, `threading`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/25695412/190597.

Comment: It took a little bit to figure out, but you're right.. my script was called threading.py, and once I changed it to something else, the script ran like it's supposed to. lesson learned: dont name your script after the module'. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

Did you happen to name your module (or another module in the working directory) `threading.py`? It would get imported ahead of the built-in `threading`, causing this exact problem.

Trying running:

```
print(threading.__file__)
```

in your module, I suspect you'll find it's not the Python built-in.