# Why do I get an error from random.choice attribute but I don't use choice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Why do I get an error about a choice attribute but I don't use choice?

This is my python code:

```
from random import randint
User, Computer = 0, randint(0,11)
# check process
while Computer != User:
   User = int(input('Enter Your number :'))
   print('Very good')
```

```
Error: 

in <module>
    print(random.choice(a))    
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'random' has no attribute 'choice' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I don't know why I get this error.

Comment: This works perfectly well, and without any error.
Reset you environment / pc and try again...

Comment: `print(random.choice(a))` - where is this line in your added code ? the current added code works as expected.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia | Yes it is irregular ! 
Because in code we haven't this line and we not use choice attribute ! i don't know  i do what 

Comment: @Malo i uninstall my interpreter (version : 3.9.1) and install last version (3.9.2) but is not OK

Comment: Have you a random.py file in your working directory or source file directory ? if you created one it may conflict with the library one. Rename it and try again.

Comment: @Malo yes i have random.py document in this code directory and i rename this document
now program is work , and i can use this code 
very very Thanks 
I do not know how to thank you

Comment: @Amirali Great! So I have written it as an answer. You can upvote and select it as good answer, this would be nice!

Comment: @Malo thanks , i accept your answer and i push useful button for your answer (Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.) and i see this message 
is it good?

Comment: @GinoMempin 
hi , thanks your answer , me saw in this page that , person doesn't have a random.py file but i had a random file in the code directory , It is noteworthy that a one person answer this question
Thanks

Comment: @Amirali But the answers/solutions are the same: that you have a random.py file and you should rename it to something else. There's even a nifty [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25695430/2745495) that teaches you how to debug things like this.

Comment: @GinoMempin Yes you  True say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you a random.py file in your working directory or source file directory ? if you created one it may conflict with the library one. Rename it and try again.